# Text is not aligning to Center in the Card UI

Tags: html, css, text-align

I have below HTML and CSS and I want to make to text align to middle(which is present in cardheader element) of the Card Element . But its not working can you please check what is wrong.

And also please suggest me is it good practice to have CSS as below

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/479nk6so/)

```
#card {
  margin : 3%;
  padding: 2%;
  border : 1%;
}

#c1,
#c2,
#c3 {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin        : 1%;
  display       : inline-block;
  width         : 30%;
  height        : 600px;
  box-shadow    : 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  transition    : 0.2s;
  border-radius : 8px;
}

#c1:hover,
#c2:hover,
#c3:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 25px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

#c1 {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

#c2 {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

#c3 {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

cardheader {
  font-size  : 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align : center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<cardheader>` is not a valid HTML tag. I've changed your code to be a `<div>` with a class for the cardheader:

Not valid:

```
<cardheader>Option 1</cardheader>
```

So change it to:

```
<div class="cardheader">Option 1</div>
```

And in CSS, change `cardheader` to `.cardheader`

https://jsfiddle.net/479nk6so/2/

Comment: How can I covert my CSS into Class instead of IDS

Comment: You only need to change the last rule's selector as I pointed out above and in the updated JSFiddle. If you want to change other IDs to classes, simply change the HTML attribute of the tag from `id=""` to `class=""` and in your CSS change pound symbols `#` to periods `.`

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display:block;` to `cardheader` resolves the text alignment issue.

Comment: This resolves the issue but `<cardheader>` is not a valid tag and should not be used in the HTML or as a CSS selector.

Comment: According to the HTML5/HTML5.1 specification, you can read it here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#writing-html-documents-elements. (HTML5 was approved way back in 2014, you shouldn't be using anything older at this point.) If you were to run this code through the HTML validation service you would see the error `"Element cardheader not allowed as child of element div in this context."`

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add `display: block` to your `#cardheader` id

Here is an updated fiddle: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/479nk6so/3/)

About your question if this is a good practice. I would suggest you use the same class for each card as it will have the same style from what I can see. This will make your css cleaner (having to style 1 class instead of many id's), and will help avoid confusion in the long run.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually i want to make only cardheader as center text aligned. Other Part should be left be left aligned within in the card

Comment: @Batman I have updated my fiddle and answer. Hope this helps!